# HtmlHelper does not contain definition for “Action”

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor, html-helper

i am trying to use Html.Action() to render partial view(GetNotificationpartial) inside layout.cshtml...but got this error , how can i fix this error

```
  <li class="dropdown">
                            <a title="الإشعارات" href="#" name="@currenUser.Id" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                <small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></small><span class="caPet"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu s pre-scrollable" id="notifications">
                                @Html.Action("Home","GetNotificationpartial") 
                                <li><h5 class="text-center">لا توجد إشعارات</h5></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use ViewComponent or jQuery for this:

Here is a sample use jQuery. If you want to use ViewComponent, I will post a sample later.

```
1. In layout page

<div id="partialContainer"></div>
<script>   
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")', {id : 1}, function(content){
            $("#partialContainer").html(content);
        });
</script>

2. Home controller 

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetData(int id)
{
   return PartialView(id);
}


3. Partial view

@model int 
<span>Values from controler :</span> @Model
```

Comment: i did it using jQuery before posting this question and i am trying to use partial view now

Comment: Hi, my friend. If you don't like using jQuery in the situation, you can use ViewComponent. Cause .Net core no action for RenderAction(). I can post a sample using ViewComponent if you want.

Comment: thank you very much for your advise i have used ViewComponent and its doing well now ,this is first time i hear about ViewComponent,

Comment: @mohammedalani1991: Well played, my friend :))

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC 5, RenderAction Invokes the specified child action method and renders the result inline in the parent view.

```
@Html.RenderAction ("Home","GetNotificationpartial");
```

[More info in MSDN about RenderAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_ChildActionExtensions_RenderAction_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_)

But in ASP.NET Core, Analyzer told you If you need to execute code, use a view component instead of a partial view.

You can render the partial view with `Partial` Tag helper :

```
<partial name="_GetNotificationpartial" />
```

Partial view names begin with an underscore (_) by naming convention.

Also, you can use `Async` method to render Partial views :

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Folder/_GetNotificationpartial.cshtml")
```

Comment: but this partial view not only view only , this partial view has controller method . so i need to render method first before partial view, i have tried this solution , it doesnt work

Comment: Is your controller returns `Partial` or `PartialViewResult` ?

Comment: return PartialView(notifications);

Comment: When i use RenderAction i gets same error(IHtmlHelpers does not contain......)